# On Ubuntu, is there a way to find out what files are NOT associated with installed apt packages?

Tags: apt, package-management

I know in RedHat, you can use `find / –exec rpm -qf {} \; |grep "is not"` to find files that are not associated with packages.  One reason I need this is to find files that are installed from source so I know what packages I need to build from source and make everything go through the package manager.  I'm coming into managing a system that someone else was loose with on the package management side of things and I need to ensure that the security is good so no stray rootkits, etc are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same method, different command:

```
$ dpkg -S /etc/profile
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /etc/profile
$ dpkg -S /etc/ssh/ssh_config 
openssh-client: /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

Comment: Do does that mean I need to use 'find / -exec dpkg -S {} \; |fgrep "no path" | cut -d' ' -f7-' ?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `find / -exec dpkg -S {} \; 2>&1 | fgrep "no path" | cut -d' ' -f7-` works for this case.

Thanks Muru!

Comment: Or: `find / -exec sh -c 'dpkg -S "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1 || echo "$1"'  _ {} \;`